# How to get the text of Checkbuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Checkbuttons gets generated dynamically and they are getting text from a python list.
I need a logic for capturing selected checkbuttons text .
As per my research everywhere they are returning the state of checkbox instead of text.
Please help.

```
cb_list =['pencil','pen','book','bag','watch','glasses','passport','clothes','shoes','cap'] 
try:
    r = 0
    cl = 1
    for op in cb_list:
        cb = Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text=op, relief=RIDGE)
        cb.grid(row=r, column=cl, sticky="W")
        r = r + 1
except Exception as e:
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.ERROR)
    logging.error(e)
    # print (e)
 selected_item = Text(self, width=30, height=20, wrap=WORD)
 selected_item.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=20, pady=20, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

 display_button = Button(self, text='DISPLAY', command=display()
 convert_button.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=20, pady=20)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You talk about entries but in above there's not even an `Entry`.

Comment: @Nae is this edited explanation ok?

Comment: I don't think so. While it turns out you want your text in `Text` instead? It still isn't [mcve]. Please go to the link and read it.

Comment: You need to specify also if their order matters or not in the Text.

Comment: I think it might be easier to use a `Listbox` rather than a `Text` widget.

Comment: I need a logic for capturing selected checkbuttons text @j_4321
I tried searching but everywhere they are returning the state of checkbox instead of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the same variable, `cb`, try using an iterable type such as `dict`ionary. You should also need to be attaching the value of `Checkbutton` to a [tkinter variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), such as `BooleanVar`, in order to easily track its status & value.

---

The code below produces a GUI that re-writes `Text` each time a `Checkbutton` is selected. It first populates a dictionary, `cbs`, with items from a list, `cb_list`, as keys and `tk.Checkbutton` objects as the values.

`Checkbutton` objects are so that each is attached to a special object, Tkinter Variable class, `BooleanVar`, which has a `get` method that returns the `Checkbutton` it is attached to's current value when called. In this case, each `Checkbutton` holds `True` if checked, and `False` if unchecked as its value.

Each `Checkbutton` is also attached to a method, `update_text`, which is called when any of the `Checkbutton` is pressed. In that method for every `Checkbutton` in `cbs`, it first checks if the `Checkbutton` has `True` value, if so it appends its `text` to a `_string`. After this has been done for all `Checkbuttons`, the method then proceeds as first `delete`ing the entire text in the `Text` widget, then it puts `_string` to the `Text`.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_text():
    global cbs
    _string = ''
    for name, checkbutton in cbs.items():
        if checkbutton.var.get():
            _string += checkbutton['text'] + '\n'
    text.delete('1.0', 'end')
    text.insert('1.0', _string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = tk.Text(root)

    cb_list =['pencil','pen','book','bag','watch','glasses','passport',
                                                'clothes','shoes','cap']
    cbs = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(cb_list):
        cbs[value] = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=value, onvalue=True,
                                offvalue=False, command=update_text)
        cbs[value].var = tk.BooleanVar(root, value=False)
        cbs[value]['variable'] = cbs[value].var

        cbs[value].grid(row=i, column=0)

    text.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

`text` is an option to `Checkbutton` widget, which means you can get its value using [`cget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method)(`widget.cget('option')`) or simply `widget['option']`.

Comment: Your answer is also giving me prompt output @Nae thank you

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to associate one `BooleanVar` to each checkbutton and store them in a list `cb_var`. Then, to display the selected items, we just have to clear the display box (I have used a `Listbox`) and then loop simultaneously through `cb_list` and `cb_var` to determine which items are selected:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
checkbutton_frame = tk.Frame(root)
checkbutton_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

def display():
    # clear listbox
    selected_item.delete(0, 'end')
    # add selected items in listbox
    for text, var in zip(cb_list, cb_var):
        if var.get():
            # the checkbutton is selected
            selected_item.insert('end', text)

cb_list = ['pencil','pen','book','bag','watch','glasses','passport','clothes','shoes','cap'] 
cb_var = []  # to store the variables associated to the checkbuttons
cl = 1
for r, op in enumerate(cb_list):
    var = tk.BooleanVar(root, False)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, variable=var, text=op, relief='ridge')
    cb.grid(row=r, column=cl, sticky="w")
    cb_var.append(var)

selected_item = tk.Listbox(root, width=30, height=20)
selected_item.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=20, pady=20, columnspan=2, sticky='e')

display_button = tk.Button(root, text='DISPLAY', command=display)
display_button.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you want to be able to change the list of items easily, you can use a function `init_checkbuttons` to create the checkbuttons from your list
of items. This function does the following things:

1. Destroy all previous checkbuttons
2. Clear the listbox
3. Create the new checkbuttons
4. Change the command of the display button

You can notice that the `display` function now takes `cb_list` and `cb_var` in argument, so that you can change them.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
checkbutton_frame = tk.Frame(root)
checkbutton_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

def display(cb_list, cb_var):
    # clear listbox
    selected_item.delete(0, 'end')
    # add selected items in listbox
    for text, var in zip(cb_list, cb_var):
        if var.get():
            # the checkbutton is selected
            selected_item.insert('end', text)

def init_checkbuttons(cb_list, cl=1):
    # destroy previous checkbuttons (assuming that checkbutton_frame only contains the checkbuttons)
    cbs = list(checkbutton_frame.children.values())
    for cb in cbs:
        cb.destroy()
    # clear listbox
    selected_item.delete(0, 'end')
    # create new checkbuttons
    cb_var = []  # to store the variables associated to the checkbuttons
    for r, op in enumerate(cb_list):
        var = tk.BooleanVar(root, False)
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, variable=var, text=op, relief='ridge')
        cb.grid(row=r, column=cl, sticky="w")
        cb_var.append(var)
    # change display command
    display_button.configure(command=lambda: display(cb_list, cb_var))

cb_list = ['pencil', 'pen', 'book', 'bag', 'watch', 'glasses', 'passport', 'clothes', 'shoes', 'cap']
cb_list2 = ['ball', 'table', 'bat']

selected_item = tk.Listbox(root, width=30, height=20)
selected_item.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=20, pady=20, columnspan=2, sticky='e')

display_button = tk.Button(root, text='DISPLAY')
display_button.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=20, pady=20)

tk.Button(root, text='Change list', command=lambda: init_checkbuttons(cb_list2)).grid(row=2, column=8)

init_checkbuttons(cb_list)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how to clear the checkbuttons ?
Now the list is this: cb_list = ['pencil','pen','book','bag','watch','glasses','passport','clothes','shoes','cap']
but if the list changes in second iteration
cb_list = ['ball','table','bat']
So I want to clear previous check buttons to get new checkbuttons
I tried with checkbutton.destroy()
but it destroys and would not create new checkbuttons