# Getting text of a checkbutton from the variable in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I am creating the checkbuttons here:

```
var = []
k=0
for i in results:
    var.append(IntVar())
    Checkbutton(frame, text = i[0], variable = var[k], wraplength=500).pack()
    k+=1
```

Here, I have obtained the variable for each check button and want to print the text of the checkbuttons that are checked:

```
# function is called when a button is clicked
def delHist():
    for i in range(len(var)):
        if var[i].get()==1:      # checking if the checkbutton is checked
            # want to print the text in the checkbutton here
```

**How can I print the text of that checkbutton using only the variable?**

Edit:
The question here seems to be similar:
[How to get the text from a checkbutton in python ? (Tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545085/how-to-get-the-text-from-a-checkbutton-in-python-tkinter)

I tried assigning `Checkbutton(frame, text = i[0], variable = var[k], wraplength=500).pack()` to a list `ch[p]` so as it iterates, it's assigned to a new object. When I added `print ch[p].get()` under the function, I get an error. 
I also tried `print ch[p].get('text')` but I get the error

> TypeError: "get()" takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the text from a checkbutton in python ? (Tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545085/how-to-get-the-text-from-a-checkbutton-in-python-tkinter)

Comment: @TheMaker I've edited the question to explain why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436622/how-to-get-the-text-of-checkbuttons

Comment: You can use `StringVar` instead of `IntVar` and set `onvalue=i[0]` and `offvalue=''` for each checkbutton.  Then if `var[i].get()` return something, then the checkbutton is checked and you can print the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `onvalue` to the same value as the text (or whatever value you want), the variable will either contain that value or an empty string.

You would need to first switch from `IntVar` to `StringVar`, and then set the `onvalue` and `offvalue`:

```
var.append(StringVar())
buttons.append(Checkbutton(tk, text = i[0], variable = var[k], wraplength=500, onvalue=i[0], offvalue=""))
```

Next, you can modify `delHist` to simply print the values that are not the empty string:

```
def delHist():
    for variable in var:
        value = variable.get()
        if value:
            print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (correct me in comments), here is what you need:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

var = []
buttons = []
k=0
def delHist():
    for i in range(len(var)):
        if var[i].get()==1:
            print(buttons[i]['text'])
for i in 'abcde':
    var.append(IntVar())
    buttons.append(Checkbutton(tk, text = i[0], variable = var[k], wraplength=500))
    buttons[-1].pack()
    k+=1

Button(text='delHist', command=delHist).pack()
```

Note that I'm appending `Checkbutton(...)` to list, not `Checkbutton(...).pack()`, and running `.pack()` method afterwards. The reason is that the first one returns a `Checkbutton` object while the second one `NoneType` - this is not jQuery.
Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`Tkinter`is OOP, therefore the opposite takes place.
Extend the `tk.Checkbutton` object and forget abbout the `variable=tk.IntVar()`.
The extended `Checkbutton` knows his `text=` and `checked` state.

### [image]

```
import tkinter as tk


class Checkbutton(tk.Checkbutton):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self._var = tk.IntVar()
        # kwargs['variable'] = self._var
        super().__init__(parent, variable=self._var, **kwargs)

    @property
    def checked(self):
        return self._var.get() == 1

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Checkbutton: {self['text']}={self.checked}"
```

> Usage:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        for text in ('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'):
            Checkbutton(self.frame, text=text, wraplength=500).pack()

        tk.Button(self, text='Show Checkbutton state', command=self.on_button_click).pack()

    def on_button_click(self):
        for ckb in self.frame.children.values():
            print(ckb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

> Output:

```
Checkbutton: option 1=False
Checkbutton: option 2=True
Checkbutton: option 3=False
```